# Light Step Integration for Open Tracing

Tags: opentracing, jaeger

I am exploring the various Tracing Systems. I was looking into Light Step recently.
I have integrated my application for OpenTracing where I use the tracer from Light Step.
Now how can view the traces I am generating. 
For example in Jaeger they had a ready to use docker image which can be used for quick demo.
Can somebody please help me here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Jaeger, LightStep is a commercial SaaS offering. If you wanted to try out their service, you'd need to contact their sales team.